# Ajax content load without refresh function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

New coder here looking for some help with getting ajax to load content into a div (content_area) without reload. So far only testing with the first two links home & about.

my js file:

```
    $(document).ready(function()    {
    //initial
    $('#content_area').load('content/home.php');

    //handle menu clicks
    $('.sf-menu li a').click(function(){
        var page = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#content_area').load('content/' + page + '.php');
        return false;
    }); 

});
```

My menu is:

```
<div class="main-menu-wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <nav class="navigation">
          <ul class="sf-menu">
            <li><a href="home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about">About Us</a></li>
```

By the way live test site is [link] http://www.newconstructionflorida.net [link]
The initial content load works, but cant get the menu nav click to work.

Comment: i don't understand your code. In HTML you put all .html files and then you append .php with that href why ?

Comment: 1) $(".sf-menu a").click 2) I am guessing it's $('#content_area') 3) again, guessing it's $('#content_area').load('content/' + page)

Comment: Only working with link for home page & about page at the moment. I am in the process of removing all html files and creating .php files instead in my content folder. Just wanted to get it to work with the first two link prior to moving forward.

Comment: @LShetty made corrections but still not loading the nav click content. Only initial page content is loading.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use

```
$('.sf-menu li a')
```

since sf-menu is not an id, but a class.

and your code needs the files in the content-folder to have a .html.php ending, like content/agents.html.php

is that intentionally?

Comment: also there is a problem in $('content_area').load('content/' + page + '.php'); specify content_area (class/ID) ?

Comment: the .html menu items will be removed (that was how it was prior to me trying to use ajax for the auto load).

Comment: corrected to:  $('#content_area').load('content/' + page + '.php');